# MinGW. Как компилировать?

Tags: c, mingw, gtk, cygwin, msys2

Начинаю изучать GTK. Работаю в Windows10. Компилирую пример с сайта GTK:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

gcc:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-1 example-1.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Компилируется нормально. Далее запускаю из консоли:

```
./example-1.exe
```

- запускается и работает как положено)

НО. При запуске из папки, вне mingw, программа выдает ошибки об отсутствующих *.dll. Далее я нашел все эти dll-ки и скопировал в папку с программой. Снова результат- программа не запускается - выдает ошибку 0xc00007b. Я сделал все на что способен на данный момент. Что еще нужно сделать, чтобы программа запустилась в Windows?

Для справки:

```
$ ntldd ./example-1.exe
        KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll (0x0000000000620000)
        msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll (0x0000000000620000)
        libgio-2.0-0.dll => F:\TCPU69\Programm\PortableApps_Platform\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000620000)
        libglib-2.0-0.dll => F:\TCPU69\Programm\PortableApps_Platform\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000db0000)
        libgobject-2.0-0.dll => F:\TCPU69\Programm\PortableApps_Platform\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000db0000)
        libgtk-3-0.dll => F:\TCPU69\Programm\PortableApps_Platform\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll (0x00000000010d0000)

$ ls
example-1.exe  libgio-2.0-0.dll  libglib-2.0-0.dll  libgmodule-2.0-0.dll  libgobject-2.0-0.dll  libgtk-3-0.dll  libpcre-1.dll  libwinpthread-1.dll
```

Проверяю дальше:

```
$ ntldd libgio-2.0-0.dll
        libgmodule-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000020000)
        libgobject-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000af0000)
        ADVAPI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll (0x0000000000ef0000)
        DNSAPI.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll (0x00000000010c0000)
        IPHLPAPI.DLL => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL (0x00000000001c0000)
        KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll (0x0000000000f90000)
        msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll (0x0000000000f90000)
        SHELL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll (0x00000000014b0000)
        USER32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll (0x0000000000f90000)
        WS2_32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll (0x00000000010c0000)
        libintl-8.dll (0x00000000001c0000)
        zlib1.dll (0x00000000001c0000)
        libglib-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000dd0000)
```

... видимо это они...недостающие библиотеки из комментариев))) интересно почему отсутствует адрес!?
попробую скопировать их в папку программы...и остальное аналогично...

```
$ ntldd libglib-2.0-0.dll
        ADVAPI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll (0x0000000000620000)
        KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll (0x0000000000e00000)
        msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll (0x0000000000e00000)
        ole32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll (0x0000000000e00000)
        libwinpthread-1.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        SHELL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll (0x0000000001230000)
        USER32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll (0x0000000000e00000)
        WS2_32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll (0x0000000000f30000)
        libintl-8.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        libpcre-1.dll (0x0000000000190000)
$ ntldd libgobject-2.0-0.dll
        libglib-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000d10000)
        KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll (0x0000000000e30000)
        msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll (0x0000000000e30000)
        libffi-6.dll (0x0000000000020000)
$ ntldd libgtk-3-0.dll
        libgdk-3-0.dll (0x0000000001320000)
        COMCTL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.17134.285_none_f956470b309229d4\COMCTL32.dll (0x0000000001a60000)
        comdlg32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\COMDLG32.dll (0x0000000001450000)
        GDI32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        IMM32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        KERNEL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.dll (0x0000000001790000)
        msvcrt.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll (0x00000000014f0000)
        ole32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll (0x0000000001790000)
        SHELL32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll (0x0000000002120000)
        USER32.dll => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll (0x0000000001790000)
        WINSPOOL.DRV => C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV (0x0000000001450000)
        libatk-1.0-0.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        libcairo-gobject-2.dll (0x0000000000020000)
        libcairo-2.dll (0x0000000001450000)
        libepoxy-0.dll (0x0000000001790000)
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        libgio-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000001790000)
        libglib-2.0-0.dll (0x00000000018f0000)
        libgmodule-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000020000)
        libgobject-2.0-0.dll (0x0000000000720000)
        libintl-8.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        libpango-1.0-0.dll (0x0000000000720000)
        libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll (0x0000000000190000)
        libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll (0x00000000001d0000)
```

И ВУАЛЯ - что получаем? Снова - ошибка про недостающие библиотеки!
Создаю новый вопрос как заскриптовать все действия по поиску и копированию  недостающих lib.[Скрипт или программа для добавления недостающих библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887714/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA)

Comment: Значит не все библиотеки скопировали . Провертеть утилитой `ldd` какие подключены библиотеки

Comment: Либо не все, либо неподходящие версии библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

[На официальном сайте GTK](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) имеется инструкция для установки зависимостей с помощью MSYS2, а также перечислены зависимости:

> **List of GTK+ dependencies**
>   **GTK+ depends on several libraries:**
>   GLib
>   cairo
>   Pango
>   ATK
>   gdk-pixbuf
>   **To run GTK+ programs you will also need:**
>   gettext-runtime
>   fontconfig
>   freetype
>   expat
>   libpng
>   zlib

*Убедитесь, что* все перечисленные библиотеки необходимых версий и их зависимости имеются , а *динамический линковщик в состоянии их найти.* Также не забудьте о библиотеке `libgcc_*.dll`. Так как у Вас приложение запускается из консоли (используется MSYS2, если не ошибаюсь), то библиотеки где-то имеются, но динамический линковщик не может их найти.