# Скрипт или программа для добавления недостающих библиотек

Tags: c, библиотеки, mingw, зависимости

Вопрос возник вследствие действий по данному вопросу:
[MinGW. Как компилировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887627/mingw-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Собственно вопрос:
Какой скрипт либо программа автоматизирует процесс добавления недостаюших файлов?

Comment: ldd + мозг. А автоматизация - тут сложно.

Comment: по ссылке windows, в метках к этому вопросу перечислены linux, ubuntu и mingw. как Вы это совместили?

Comment: поправил метки.

Comment: Dependency Walker https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker не добавляет автоматически зависимости?